# C# deserialization

Tags: c#, json

How to deserialize with keyvaluepair the above json

```
string stations = [{"2":false,"1":"Aforre","0":"WS6"},{"2":false,"1":"Alodtau","0":"WS3"},{"2":false,"1":"Balimo Station","0":"WS36"}]
```

I what like this

```
var get = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(stations);
```

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense. A dictionary can only have one key and one value. What would the value of key `"2"` be if there are multiple different values in the array? Second, as mentioned, the source object is an array. You should deserialize it as such and iterate over it to transform the data as you require

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can try using dynamic variable as following:

```
 string stations = "[{'2':false,'1':'Aforre','0':'WS6'},{'2':false,'1':'Alodtau','0':'WS3'},{'2':false,'1':'Balimo Station','0':'WS36'}]";
 var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 dynamic serializevalues = serializer.DeserializeObject(stations);
 var valueof1 = serializevalues[0]["1"];
 Response.Write(valueof1);
```

The above will print output "Aforre'.

Comment: hey, u simply copied my answer and that also 2mins after :D

Comment: hey i am not copied ur answer.

Comment: u did, otherwise, you would have know, dynamic has nothing to do with it here, you could have used var instead. -1

Comment: Hey guys i very happy for ur reply but both guys code tell same matter only but i dont know what to say and thanks for spending ur valuable time for me ..........

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
string stations = "[{'2':false,'1':'Aforre','0':'WS6'},{'2':false,'1':'Alodtau','0':'WS3'},{'2':false,'1':'Balimo Station','0':'WS36'}]";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic value = serializer.DeserializeObject(stations);
```

and you can access objects like:

```
var a = value[0]["0"];
```

and a will have "WS6" (according to your JSON)

Comment: this is copied answer.

Comment: common dude, you're in computer science field, both our answers has timestamp, mine is earlier, no way I could have copied it, besides, I formatted that json on my PC, those double quotes to single :D. haha @user3129000

Answer (score 1):

The JSON shown is an array. You might try desetializing to:

```
Dictionary<string, object>[]
```

i.e.

```
var get = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>[]>(stations);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best option is create a class that consist of all keyvalue pair and then deserialize json string to the object of created class